# Remove duplicate records from a csv file considering single column

Tags: shell, awk, csh, tcsh

I have a file with records in such a type-

```
,laac_repo,cntrylist,idlist,domlist,typelist
1,22DE17,BA,S6CD6728,24JA13,6A
2,12FE18,AA,S6FD7688,25DA15,7D
3,22DE17,BA,S6CD6728,24JA13,6A
4,12FE18,AA,S6FD7688,25DA15,7D
```

I want to remove duplicate records considering 4th column which has ***"S6CD6728"*** these type of record and skipping first row which is

```
",laac_repo,cntrylist,idlist,domlist,type list"
```

I have tried

```
awk '{a[$4]++}!(a[$4]-1)' filename
```

And also tried

```
awk 'FNR > 1 {a[$4]++}!(a[$4]-1)' filename
```

The expected output is-

```
,laac_repo,cntrylist,idlist,domlist,typelist
1,22DE17,BA,S6CD6728,24JA13,6A
2,12FE18,AA,S6FD7688,25DA15,7D
```

P.S file has more than 10 million records, please suggest solution w.r.t that.( If any script given much appreciated, instead of single command).

Comment: please update the question to show the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1 && \!seen[$4]++' filename
```

```
1,22DE17,BA,S6CD6728,24JA13,6A
2,12FE18,AA,S6FD7688,25DA15,7D
```

```
awk -F, '\!seen[$4]++' filename
```

```
,laac_repo,cntrylist,idlist,domlist,typelist
1,22DE17,BA,S6CD6728,24JA13,6A
2,12FE18,AA,S6FD7688,25DA15,7D
```